# Cakephp How to use SQL month function in cakephp find method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query like

```
SELECT count(id),DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M') from searches group by month(created)
```

The output that I got like

```
count(id)   DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M')   
16             August
2              September
```

I applied this query in cakephp find method like below

```
$total = $this->Searches->find('count',[
             'fields'=>['Searches.id',DATE_FORMAT('created','%M')],
             'group' =>[month('Searches.created')]
]);
```

1st I am getting error date_format() expects parameter 1. How can I apply my top sql query in cakephp find method ? 
I am using cakephp 3 version.

Answer (score 1):

The query builder has a `func()` method that allows you to use SQL functions.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

```
$time = $query->func()->date_format([
    'created' => 'identifier',
    "'%M'" => 'literal'
]);
```

You can then use that `$time` variable in your query.